# Exported UTI not being picked up by macOS

Tags: macos, cocoa, nsdocument, uti

I'm trying to export a UTI in my application, but macOS (10.3.2) is not picking it up. I've replicated my issue in a smaller project. Here's the relevant part of `info.plist`:

```
<key>UTExportedTypeDeclarations</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>UTTypeConformsTo</key>
        <array>
            <string>public.plain-text</string>
        </array>
        <key>UTTypeDescription</key>
        <string>Demo of custom file support</string>
        <key>UTTypeIconFile</key>
        <string>File-512</string>
        <key>UTTypeIdentifier</key>
        <string>am.customfiledemo.demotxt</string>
        <key>UTTypeTagSpecification</key>
        <dict>
            <key>public.filename-extension</key>
            <array>
                <string>demotxt</string>
            </array>
            <array/>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</array>
```

I've tried rebooting, and even rebuilding the launch services database, to no effect:

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/LaunchServices.framework/Versions/A/Support/lsregister -kill -r -domain local -domain ststem -domain user -v
```

When I check my file's UTI with

```
mdls -name kMDItemContentType -name kMDItemContentTypeTree file.demotxt
```

I get a dynamic (`dyn.*`) UTI, rather than `am.customfiledemo.demotxt`

```
kMDItemContentType                 = "dyn.ah62d4rv4ge80k3prr74hu7a"
kMDItemContentTypeTree             = (
    "dyn.ah62d4rv4ge80k3prr74hu7a",
    "public.data",
    "public.item"
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make the UTI conform to `public.data`, or `com.apple.package`:

> Although a custom UTI can conform to any UTI, `public.data` or `com.apple.package` must be at the root of the conformance hierarchy for all custom UTIs that are file formats (such as documents); otherwise, the system can’t tell if an item on disk has that UTI.

- [Uniform Type Identifiers Overview, Declaring New Uniform Type Identifiers, Recommendations for Declaring new Uniform Type Identifiers](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/understanding_utis/understand_utis_declare/understand_utis_declare.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001319-CH204-SW4)